# How to pass large input to powershell

Tags: powershell

Assuming powershell has a limit of N characters in its command, how can I pass more than N chars to the powershell cmdlet?  Based on https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/830473 link, it seems that the character limit is 8191 but it says that for cmd.exe, not sure what is the size limit for powershell. So if I have an input of size more than >8k, can I redirect the input to the powershell to circumvent this problem (solution based on what is mentioned in the referenced document).

Eg:

powershell console $> echo “a very long string” // the whole command including the echo and the very long string totalling less than 8192 chars on the powershell console. When I execute this I get the whole string as the output on the console

powershell console $> echo “a very long string // Try to add characters to the very long string, powershell doesn’t allow me to add more chars to the very long string if the total goes above 8192 since I guess I have reached the limit on the number of characters I can enter.

What I want:

powershell console $> echo  // Place my input (which is more than 8192 chars) in a file and provide that as an input to echo and echo should display the complete string on the console thereby circumventing the limitation of the number of chars in a command.

The command echo I have used is only for representation purpose and I want to use a custom cmdlet instead of that so please consider this a valid scenario.

Edit 2:

psm1 file:

```
Function DoSomething {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
     Mandatory = $False)
    ]
    [string]$v1,

    [Parameter(
     Mandatory = $False)
    ]
    [string]$v2)

    Begin {}

  Process {
    Write-Output "hello $v1 | $v2"
  }
}
```

Text File Content say content.txt(short for representation purpose but assume this can be more than 8k characters):

```
-v1 "t1" -v2 "qwe"
```

Now when I do

```
powershell Console$> DoSomething (Get-Content content.txt)
```

the output that I get is

```
hello -v1 "t1" -v2 "qwe" |
```

I expect the output to be

```
hello -v1 "t1" | -v2 "qwe"
```

so that the execution of the cmdlet can happen without any issues. I tried this with the example of more than 8k characters in the text file and it is able to print the output, it is just that the parameters aren't getting separated. The command to provide the input to the cmdlet doesn't have to be Get-Content, it can be anything as long as it works.

Comment: You're assuming that PowerShell has a limit on input, but basing this limit off of CMD.EXE?  Is that because you're going to be expecting input to pass TO CMD.EXE from PowerShell, or vice-versa?  Can you clarify what cmdlet you're trying to run?  Provide a specific [mcve] for us?

Comment: @gravity Thanks for the reply. No, the input isn't going to be passed on to CMD.exe or vice-versa. I read a lot of threads and I came across one that mentioned 8k. I gave this link since it talked about the alternate explanation.

To your question about what cmdlet I am trying to run, so I was just trying an echo "<randomg string>", the random string generated by copying and expanding the input and I hit the limit at some where around 8175 so its closer to 8192. I may eventually have an input that might exceed 8k so need to account for that. This is for a custom cmdlet.

Comment: I'd recommend showing us a [mcve], still.  It's not entirely clear what you're running into, as far as the limits go.  I have a guess, but I'd rather not answer if the question isn't explicitly clear.  For example, I'm not sure why you're using `echo` in a PowerShell cmdlet either.

Comment: @gravity I just care about the length of the input so does it matter if I am using echo or something else? I just have a custom cmdlet which accepts various input parameters and does operations using those parameters. And it is possible that those input parameters can go very large and I just want to make sure that the powershell limit of a certain number of characters is not hit. I have edited the question with an example of some sort. Let me know if that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Is there an actual problem you need resolved, or are you just asking us to do your testing for you?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I do have an actual problem that needs to be resolved and no I am not asking you guys to do testing for me. I just want to know how I can handle the case where the input size is very large (input with size more than 8k chars) since with what I have tested it seems that powershell has a limit to the number of characters it can handle (I have found no official documentation but I see it when I try my echo example). I just want to make sure that I employ a method that doesn't break irrespective of the input size....

Comment: ... I have tried Get-Content <fileName> and piped that to my custom cmdlet but the cmdlet is supposed to handle different args but when I pipe Get-Content output it just gets assigned to one variable. I have tried capturing the output in a variable and passing that to my custom cmdlet but again it gets assigned to only one variable.

Comment: Show your cmdlet and how you call it, show the result you expected as well as the result you actually got, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers can you have a look now?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how parameters in PowerShell functions work. The output of `Get-Content` is an array of strings (one string for each line in the file), but the entire array is passed to the first parameter. Also, a string isn't magically split so that the substrings can go to several parameters. How should PowerShell know which way to split the string?

A better way to deal with such input data is to have your function accept input from the pipeline:

```
Function DoSomething {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$false,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string]$v1,

    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$false,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string]$v2
  )

  Process {
    Write-Output "hello $v1 | $v2"
  }
}
```

and define the data as a CSV (column names matching the parameter names):

```
v1,v2
"-v1 ""t1""","-v2 ""qwe"""
```

so that you can pipe the data into the function:

```
Import-Csv content.csv | DoSomething
```

With the function built like this you could also define the data as a hashtable and [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) it:

```
$data = @{
  'v1' = '-v1 "t1"'
  'v2' = '-v2 ""qwe"'
}

DoSomething @data
```

For more information about function parameters see [`about_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847824.aspx) and [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx).

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense and thanks for the explanation. So for my scenario there are lot of cmdlets that are like DoSomething for whom the ValuefromPipeline property is not set. Also, so far, the input has been handled by directly passing it to the cmdlet like "DoSomething <parameter(s)>", but just recently we discovered that the input may grow bigger than 8k hence need a different approach in which we don't have to modify the way input is brought in as well how the existing cmdlets are written. So I was thinking if there was something like "DoSomething < Filename" which probably would ...

Comment: ... have been perfect for me if it worked. I understand that may not be possible but just wanted to know if there is any way that can be done since changing the cmdlets and the inputs may not be feasible for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Else you can pass a path file where content of this file is used in your script ps. No limit then...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not exactly sure what you mean by path file. Can you please elaborate?